# Trouble installing R package on Heroku

Tags: r, heroku

I am trying to install package [Boom](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Boom/index.html) for R on heroku. I am using this [R buildpack](https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r) to deploy R packages. I am getting a timeout error and  build fails after getting stuck for quite long at

```
* installing *source* package 'Boom' ...
** package 'Boom' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
Models/Glm/PosteriorSamplers/fill_poisson_mixture_approximation_table_2.cpp: In function 'void BOOM::fill_poisson_mixture_approximation_table_2(BOOM::NormalMixtureApproximationTable*)':
Models/Glm/PosteriorSamplers/fill_poisson_mixture_approximation_table_2.cpp:7:8: note: variable tracking size limit exceeded with -fvar-tracking-assignments, retrying without
   void fill_poisson_mixture_approximation_table_2(
        ^
Models/Glm/PosteriorSamplers/fill_poisson_mixture_approximation_table_3.cpp: In function 'void BOOM::fill_poisson_mixture_approximation_table_3(BOOM::NormalMixtureApproximationTable*)':
Models/Glm/PosteriorSamplers/fill_poisson_mixture_approximation_table_3.cpp:7:8: note: variable tracking size limit exceeded with -fvar-tracking-assignments, retrying without
   void fill_poisson_mixture_approximation_table_3(
        ^

 !     Timed out compiling Multipack app (15 minutes)
 !     See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#time-limit
```

Not sure what options do I have from here. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work by using heroku [apt buildpack](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-apt) and then use [deb of R packages](https://launchpad.net/~marutter/+archive/ubuntu/c2d4u/). Works like a charm. Another thing to note is that you may need to add the path of library installations from apt which is different from the default R install locations.